# Ant build for Android app fails with duplicate res file error

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, ant

I've been creating my app .apk using Eclipse export for some while, but I'd now like to build using ant so I can customize the process. Following advice elsewhere, I used the "android create project" command to generate a suitable build.xml file in a temp project (and then modified it).

When I build, it fails with a duplicate file error in the package step:

```
-package:
[apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.
[apkbuilder] Creating MyApp-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
[apkbuilder] Found duplicate file for APK: res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png
[apkbuilder] Origin 1: /home/chris/temp/MyApp/MyApp.ap_
[apkbuilder] Origin 2: /home/chris/git/MyApp/MyApp/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png
...
 /home/chris/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/ant/build.xml:310: com.android.sdklib.build.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files at the same path inside the APK
```

My ant properties are:

```
source.dir=/home/chris/git/MyApp/MyApp
out.dir=/home/chris/temp/MyApp
```

It seems to be a collision between the contents of the res directory and the intermediate .ap_ resource package file created during the build. I don't understand why packaging would be including contents from both of these sources, as duplicates would appear to be the inevitable result.

I originally thought the problem was caused by the res subdirs (drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi) all containing a file with the same name (icon.png), but I tried naming these differently and the error still occurred. In any case the Eclipse export build handles them without a problem.

This problem appears similar
[Android aapt duplicate files error when building with ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561110/android-aapt-duplicate-files-error-when-building-with-ant) but in that case the person was creating their own build.xml where I am using the one provided in the android sdk.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually discovered what was causing the problem, although not necessarily why.

In ant.properties,

```
source.dir=/home/chris/git/MyApp/MyApp
```

should have been

```
source.dir=/home/chris/git/MyApp/MyApp/src
```

I only created ant.properties because the project is under git control and I assumed I needed specify where the input is as it's not in the normal place (within the workspace). It turns out I didn't need to do this as the build is smart enough to work it out from other properties.

I've provided this just in case someone else runs into the same problem.